# How to configure JWT authentication in springboot 2.2.7? Unable to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is not available in Spring Boot 2.2.7 .  I get `WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration` but could not find an example on how to work with this. I need to override the configure method which is available in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. How to get this class or is there any workaround?

I have initialised the project using Spring Initializr and trying to establish a basic JWT authorisation.

My pom.xml is given below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.isodro.learning</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>spring-security-jwt</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

Tried adding the below dependencies:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Replace `WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor ` with `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and check

Comment: that was a spelling mistake, I changed it in the question. Thanks for pointing